# How to use overflow with flex-grow

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code:

```css
html,
body,
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  background: #ddd;
}

#width {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}

#remaining {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#resize {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="width">Width</div>
    <div id="remaining">
      <div id="resize">Resize</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is what I am trying to make:

- You can resize `#width`
- You can resize `#resize`

The issue is that when I resize `#resize`, `#width` shrinks to make room for it.
What I am looking for is when I resize, `#remaining` shows a scroll bar, and doesn't resize anything else.

I believe that this is happening because `#remaining` doesn't have a `width` property, but instead `flex-grow`. And so it allows it to vary in width, because it doesn't have a set width.

I am looking for a pure HTML/CSS answer, but JavaScript would work too. (of course as long as it is reliable, won't break, and doesn't massively slow down execution using methods such as `setInterval`)

I also do want to say that I am using a flex layout on `#container` **only** for the purpose of making `#remaining` take up all of the remaining space, and if `display: flex` is removed, it would still work with the full code that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you abandon the `flex:grow` and instead calculate the width of `remaining` in the css it works.

```
.remaining{
   width: calc(100% - 200px);
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

With a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ux46hp5/)